# Trouble with Expo Go's Automatic Update (Hot Reload Not Working)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, hot-reload, expo-go

I am trying to make an app using React Native's Expo Go on Windows 11, and I cannot see any editing changes in the app once it started running.

I ran the app on web using `npm run web`, and I could see some text templates showing. When I tried editing the tsx files associated with the app, it does not automatically reload and show the edited texts (it only worked in the first run), even though the console showed me:

```
λ Bundled 33ms (node_modules/expo-router/node/render.js)
Web Bundled 125ms (node_modules/expo-router/entry.js)
λ  WARN  props.pointerEvents is deprecated. Use style.pointerEvents 
λ  WARN  accessibilityRole is deprecated. Use role.
λ  WARN  selectable prop is deprecated. Use styles.userSelect.
```

Additionally there was a warning message, which I don't know if it is super important and should be addressed:

```
Starting project at /mnt/c/Users/galva/Desktop/project
(node:1134) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```